Complex Sum and Integral Equation with Logarithmic and Trigonometric Components
Question: Are there any software that can find the solutions ,if there are any, to this equation? Or maybe it can be solved by hand in a way I have not thought of.
The equation in question is :
$$\begin{aligned}
& \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log _2\left(\sqrt[3]{x^2+1}\right)}{n^2}+\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\ln \left(\sin ^2(\theta)+\cos ^3(\theta)\right)}{\tan (\theta) \cdot \sin (\theta)} d \theta+\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^5+e^{i \pi}}}{x^2-\sqrt{3} x+2}\right)+\log _5\left(\frac{x^4+i \sqrt{x}-e^{i x}}{x^{3 / 2}+\frac{1}{x^2-1}}\right) \\
& =i\left(\frac{e^{i x}+\frac{1}{x+2}}{\sqrt{x^6-2 x+\ln (x+1)}}+\frac{\left(x^2+\sin (x)\right)^{3 / 2}}{x-\tan ^{-1}(x)}\right)+\frac{1}{\cos ^4(x)}+i \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)+\frac{1}{x^{1 / 3}}
\end{aligned}$$
I was able to do the following simplifications by hand.
First term : $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\log _2\left(\sqrt[3]{x^2+1}\right)}{n^2}$ is just $\log _2\left(\sqrt[3]{x^2+1}\right) \cdot \zeta(2)$
The integral in the second term , according to Wolfram, is $I\approx −0.3160510629856186$
Noting that $e^{\pi i}=-1$ the third term is $\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^5-1}}{x^2-\sqrt{3} x+2}\right)$
Fourth term , I could not simplify at all.
On the right side , factoring out $i$ from the first and 3rd term was the only thing i was able to do .
So the equation turned into :
$$\log _2\left(\sqrt[3]{x^2+1}\right) \cdot \zeta(2)+I+\left(\frac{\sqrt{x^5-1}}{x^2-\sqrt{3} x+2}\right)+\log _5\left(\frac{x^4+i \sqrt{x}-e^{i x}}{x^{3 / 2}+\frac{1}{x^2-1}}\right)=i\left(\frac{e^{i x}+\frac{1}{x+2}}{\sqrt{x^6-2 x+\ln (x+1)}}+\frac{\left(x^2+\sin (x)\right)^{3 / 2}}{x-\tan ^{-1}(x)}+ \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\right)\right)+\frac{1}{\cos ^4(x)}+\frac{1}{x^{1 / 3}}$$
I am thinking that, somehow we can break the LHS to real and imaginary parts separately and compare respectively. I'm also noticing that we may have some domain issues. And this is exactly why I am interested in a way that a computer can solve this.
Context This was posted on a discord aerospace engineering forum, so I suppose it might have something to do with that?!, although I doubt it and think it's more likely an AI generated equation.
Thanks in advance for any help.

This equation seems very unlikely to have a nice solution unless it was artificially constructed to have said solution. Also, you are one point taking the logarithm of a complex number. This means that log is multi-valued, making the equation even more complicated.

@YvesDaoust If this equation is part of a challenge, it may intentionally allow for either interpretation. However, treating x as complex aligns with the presence of complex terms and multi-valued functions, which would not make as much sense in a purely real context.
